# is it possible to make SmartRefresher preload more content before reach buttom

Tags: flutter

Now I am using `SmartRefresher` in flutter to load more in my app, but it must trigger a pull when the content reach the button of view, I read the document and find configuration about header reload:

```
 headerTriggerDistance: 80.0,        // header trigger refresh trigger distance
```

is it possible to make button trigger load more before reach the button? this is my code:

```
child: CupertinoScrollbar(
                    child:SmartRefresher(
                    onRefresh: () {
                      _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
                    },
                    enablePullUp: true,
                    enablePullDown: true,
                    controller: _refreshController,
                    onLoading: () {
                      dispatch(
                          HomeListDefaultActionCreator.onLoadingMoreArticles(
                              articleRequest));
                      _refreshController.loadComplete();
                    },
                    footer: CustomFooter(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, LoadStatus mode) {
                        Widget body;
                        if (mode == LoadStatus.idle) {
                          body = Text("上拉加载更多");
                        } else if (mode == LoadStatus.loading) {
                          //body =  CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                        } else if (mode == LoadStatus.failed) {
                          body = Text("加载失败!点击重试!");
                        } else if (mode == LoadStatus.canLoading) {
                          body = Text("release to load more");
                        } else {
                          body = Text("No more Data");
                        }
                        return Container(
                          height: 55.0,
                          child: Center(child: body),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    child: CustomScrollView()
)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your CustomScrollView with a NotificationListener and then use the onNotification property to do something when the scroll position gets close to the bottom of the scroll content.

Here's an [example](http://%20https://link.medium.com/rNlGJDRpVcb) of how to use the NotificationListener.

Answer (score 0):

Now I do it like this:

```
return NotificationListener(
                onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
                  if (scrollNotification is! ScrollNotification) {
                    return false;
                  }
                  autoPreloadMoreArticles(scrollNotification);
                  return true;
                }
}
```

and load more articles:

```
void autoPreloadMoreArticles(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
      ScrollMetrics metrics = notification.metrics;
      double buttonDistance = metrics.extentAfter;
      if (buttonDistance < 800 && !isDispatched) {
        isDispatched = true;
        _loadingMoreArticle();
      }
      if (buttonDistance > 800) {
        isDispatched = false;
      }
    }
  }
```